How can I get a specific color from a .png picture with OpenCV and Python
I want to check if a PNG-image contains a specific color.
I use this tutorial
This is the image:

I want to check if the light green color exist. In RGB it is: [165, 209, 103]
This is my script:
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("01.png")
hsvimg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lb = np.array([68, 100, 100])
ub = np.array([88, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsvimg, lb, ub)
if 255 in mask:
    print("true")  

I get the range from the script in the tutorial. It says the HSV color is [78, 129, 209].
Is this right?
But the script doesn't return true.
Here is a second picture I have trouble with:


If you want to check for existence of pixels with specific RGB triplet, why are you converting to HSV in the first place?

All paths and examples for Python use OpenCv and convert the colour. Are there other possibilities?

when you are converting to HSV, you get an image that should be used with an HSV threshold, not RGB threshold. To fix this use cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB

@TinoD I am using the HSV threshold, don't I? The RGB Color is [165, 209, 103], I think the HSV color is [78, 129, 209] and my range is from [68, 100, 100] to [88, 255, 255]

Just use inRange on the BGR image (making sure you define your colour using BGR as well). Also that green isn't what you claim, most of the stripe is around RGB value of(174,208,116), but it's not consistent, so maybe you're not finding anything due to looking for the wrong thing. Something like cv2.inRange(image, (112, 202, 172), (118, 208, 178)) catches the whole stripe quite well.

@DanMašekThank you! this works with mask = cv2.inRange(image, (112, 202, 160), (118, 215, 170))
I think you has a wrong color causing the upload quality, but your way works. Perfect :)

@TinoD there's no point in BGR2RGB when one can just flip the RGB tuple to be BGR. that is cheaper.

@ChristophRackwitz one of the two, definetly not both

@TinoD Yes, I am using the image directly, don't convert it anymore and flip the RGB tuple. But strangely enough, it only works with the one green color, on other images with other colors it don't work and I don't know why.

are you always trying to identify a green color?

No, I am checking with multiple colors. My code is in a new answer.

to amend your question, [edit] it. you shouldn't post an "answer" that is really a question. this is not a regular forum. SO has a different format.

those target colors look like they span greenish yellow, reddish yellow, and red... so at worst, it's a matter of the specific values being too dark or too bright or something like that.

you definitely need to check what you're picking. those ranges don't match with what I can pick from that picture you present ( https://i.sstatic.net/k5mW3.png ) you really need to look at the mask that comes out of your code.

@ChristophRackwitz Thank you. Very strange, it's a screenshot of a website, the RGB values come directly from the CSS (and Photoshop returns the same)... I will have a look.

Photoshop? screenshot of a website? don't use exotic color spaces. OpenCV doesn't handle that.

You can check this answer for understanding how to select the filter values for the colors.
Checking this, I think for green, lb is [36, 25, 25] and  ub is [70, 255, 255], but you can change according to which shade of green you need.
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("green.png")
hsvimg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lb = np.array([36, 25, 25])
ub = np.array([70, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsvimg, lb, ub)
if 255 in mask:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")

output
true

